# Add emoji to Motorola

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, emoticons

I have an unlocked Motorola Moto X running 5.1. I want to add [tennis emojis, like these](http://emojipedia.org/tennis-racquet-and-ball/). How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first enable the Emoji Keyboard under the iWnn IME. After enabling this, open any active text area and open the iWnn Emoji Keyboard and select the Car emoji icon group() and scroll down a bit. You'll be able to find the Tennis racket and ball emoji (Unicode U+1F3BE) like this,

[image: Tennis_Racket_Emoji]

<sub>Image and source: [Emojibase](https://www.emojibase.com/emoji/1f3be/tennisracquetandball)</sub>

Here's a screenshot of it,

[image: iWnn_Emoji_Keyboard_Tennis_Emoji]

<sub>iWnn Emoji Keyboard - Tennis ball racket emoji (Click to enlarge)</sub>

In old Android versions it is dislayed like this

Alternatively, you can also use the shortcode `:tennis:` to add the tennis racquet and ball emoji to your messages which works in most of the phones.